# Oracle stored procedure SQL query assign to variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a column containing a SQL query, and I want to assign a record to a different table according to the result of this query. My code is as below.

Can I make such an assignment in the stored procedure?

```
l_sel_sql := l_sel_query_rec.SQL_QUERY;
```

`sql_query` content: apostrophe included

```
  'SELECT  MBB_NO AS mbb_no, clob_column AS CLOB1, JSON_OBJECT(MBB_NO RETURNING CLOB) AS DEL_DATA FROM A '
```

My code is like this:

```
create or replace procedure SP_DELETED
is
 TYPE sql_query_type IS RECORD
   (
      TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
      COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
      SQL_QUERY VARCHAR2(2500)
   );
    TYPE json_data_type IS RECORD
   (
      MBB_NO NUMBER,
      CLOB1   clob,
      CLOB2   CLOB,  
      DEL_DATA   CLOB
   );
   
    l_sel_query         VARCHAR2(2500);
    l_sel_query_cur     SYS_REFCURSOR;
    l_sel_query_rec     sql_query_type;
    l_sel_sql           VARCHAR2 (2500);
    l_deleted_cur       SYS_REFCURSOR;
    l_deleted_rec       json_data_type;
    r_del_data          KV_DELETED%ROWTYPE;
    
 
begin 
           l_sel_query := 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME , SQL_QUERY FROM STORE_PROCEDURE ';
            open l_sel_query_cur for l_sel_query;
            loop
                fetch l_sel_query_cur into l_sel_query_rec;
                exit when l_sel_query_cur%notfound;
                
                    *l_sel_sql := l_sel_query_rec.SQL_QUERY;* 
                    open l_deleted_cur for l_sel_sql;
                    loop 
                        fetch l_deleted_cur into l_deleted_rec;
                        exit when l_deleted_cur%notfound;
                            r_del_data.TABLE_NAME := l_sel_query_rec.TABLE_NAME;
                            r_del_data.COLUMN_NAME := l_sel_query_rec.COLUMN_NAME;
                            r_del_data.TABLE_KEY :=  l_deleted_rec.MBB_NO;                    
                            r_del_data.DELETED_DOCUMENT_JSON := l_deleted_rec.DEL_DATA;
                            r_del_data.DELETED_DOCUMENT_CLOB1 := l_deleted_rec.CLOB1;
                            
                        Insert into KV_DELETED
                        values r_del_data;
                    end loop;
                    close l_deleted_cur;
            end loop;
            close l_sel_query_cur;
end;
```

Comment: I think you need [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-30ADFC05-8DFB-4C8A-831D-426C2E97F217)

Comment: Do you get an error message? What is the output? Regarding your questions: as far as I can tell, the statement `l_sel_sql := l_sel_query_rec.SQL_QUERY;` seems to be fine as just just assign a varchar2 column to a varchar2 variable. Why should this not be valid?

Comment: Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and the error message you have.